# Is there any reason unbind and then bind events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for instance,

```js
$(".bundle").unbind("click")
  .bind("click", function() {
    // complete your task onclick here
  });
```

What's the purpose of unbind click in here? any differences with having only

```js
.bind("click", function(){

})
```

Comment: Each `.bind` will add new event, not overwriting previous one. IMO it indicates bad coding

Comment: We have no way of knowing if that code has a purpose or is a waste of time without context.

Comment: When you create a plugin and don't want to add the same event multiple times, when calling the plugin again you can unbind all events.

Answer (score 4):

First, `bind()` and `unbind()` are both [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/) in favour of `on()` and `off()`.

To your question, `bind()` / `on()` are additive. Each time you call them, they add a new event listener.

```js
$(".bundle")
  .on("click", () => {
    console.log("Click handled by listener #1");
  });
  
$(".bundle")
  .on("click", () => {
    console.log("Click handled by listener #2");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="bundle">Click me</button>
```

The reason to use `unbind()` / `off()` is to remove previous listeners.

```js
$(".bundle")
  .on("click", () => {
    console.log("Click handled by listener #1");
  });
  
$(".bundle")
  .off("click")  
  .on("click", () => {
    console.log("Click handled by listener #2");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="bundle">Click me</button>
```